# Uncaught exception: java.lang.NullPointerException: null

Tags: jmeter

getting below execpiton during Jmeter5.1.1, 50 users 1 iteration execution

```
2020-01-22 08:20:23,976 ERROR o.a.j.JMeter: Uncaught exception: 
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.sun.java.swing.plaf.windows.WindowsTableHeaderUI$XPDefaultRenderer.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.CellRendererPane.paintComponent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paintCell(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicTableHeaderUI.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.plaf.ComponentUI.update(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintComponent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JViewport.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JSplitPane.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JLayeredPane.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintChildren(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paintToOffscreen(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paintDoubleBuffered(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$PaintManager.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.GraphicsCallback$PaintCallback.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runOneComponent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at sun.awt.SunGraphicsCallback.runComponents(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.Container.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.Window.paint(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$4.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$1200(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$500(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_112]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just don't use JMeter GUI for running the tests, you should use GUI only for tests development and/or debugging. 50 users may be too high for GUI mode.

Once you finish test script creation and run it with 1-2 users/loops to ensure that it's doing what it is supposed to be doing you should close JMeter GUI and run your test like:

```
jmeter -n -t test.jmx -l result.jtl
```

Once your test is finished you can open `result.jtl` file with the [listener](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/listeners.html) of your choice and analyze the results or [generate a HTML Reporting Dashboard from the results file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html#report_only).

References:

- [Load Test Running](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#load_test_running)
- [How Do I Run JMeter in Non-GUI Mode?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/dear-abby-blazemeter-how-do-i-run-jmeter-non-gui-mode/)